# Display a line chart based on data(lines and curves)

Tags: spotfire

I would like to know how to display usl along with the data in spotfire's lines and curves settings.
I would like to express the changed data by line & curve instead of Y axis chart.

If there is data that changes to two values, I want to express it as one line instead of two lines.
but, Curve from data tabel:Custom curve or Horizontal Line draws two lines